# Uploading MySQL with FileZilla

Tags: mysql, web, filezilla

When I upload my website is there a way to upload MySQL with it using FileZilla?

I want both my website and MySQL inside FileZilla.

Comment: You want to upload the .sql files? Or are you asking for the migration to DB?

Comment: I was wondering if there is  way to upload .sql files

Comment: Well you can upload any files...

Answer (score 0):

May you want to export and import your database to mysql Server.

Use phpmyadmin tool (is simple) or do this to commande line.